# Bitbucket OAuth returns "Could not verify OAuth request."

Tags: oauth, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm attempting to use bitbucket's API through Python with rauth.  My `get_request_token` call fails with the error: `Key Error: 'Decoder failed to handle oauth_token with data as returned by provider. A different decoder may be needed. Provider returned: Could not verify OAuth request.'`

I wrote and tested this code a year ago and it worked then (on the same server, in fact).  What is wrong now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My server's clock was not within five minutes of bitbucket's.

The answer was here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshooting+OAuth+Requests

Installing ntp solved this for me (on ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install ntp`).

Comment: Mercy!  This was such a valuable find after hours of hair-pulling.  Thanks a ton.  Why don't they just post a better error message?!?

Comment: Exactly... "An error occurred, because an error occurred" - one of programmer's the worst nightmares ;/