# Issue with oauth1.0a access token on bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket-api

I am really confused that I can successfully get the request token using the oauth1.0a.js API, but not the access token. Always get 'Could not verify OAuth request.' even with the token verifier provided in the form for the POST request. Anyone has the same problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitbucket OAuth returns "Could not verify OAuth request."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835265/bitbucket-oauth-returns-could-not-verify-oauth-request)

Comment: But I can get request token, that means my provided timestamp is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself today, the reason I found to cause it is that the API did not add the oauth_verifier return at call back url to Basestring for the signature computation.(Maybe because it is the oauth1.0a feature) Manually add it. It solves the problem.

Comment: I got the exactly same error. Can you give specific guide to fix it?

Comment: Did you try adding the oauth_verifier returned before to join the later signature? That is the main problem for me.